# Type Mismatch from WCF Service

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I have a WCF service that returns a datatable, but when I try to save the datatable into a variable I get a type mistmatch. How do you fix this?

IService1.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    DataTable GetPeople();
}
```

Service1.cs:

```
public DataTable GetPeople()
{
     DataTable tbl = new DataTable("testTbl");
     return tbl;
}
```

Main WPF application:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ServiceReference1.Service1Client objservice = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    DataTable dt = objservice.GetPeople();
}
```

On the last line it will not even let me compile and says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'ServiceReference1.GetPeopleResponseGetPeopleResult' to 'System.Data.DataTable'"

I have tried casting but I cannot figure out how to get this to work.

Comment: Based on the error you are giving, I would comment you very likely are assuming the WCF method does return a DataTable, but in fact is not returning that type. It should in fact return that type, but sometimes adding a WCF reference does change the types. Check the returned type (right click on the method -> go to definition), see what does return and convert that structure into a DataTable.

Comment: You can refer to the tutorial of [WCF service returning data table](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deepak.sharma00/how-to-return-a-datatable-from-wcf-service/)